# What sets are these black curved pieces with fine-lined stickers from?

Tags: part-identification

I got these pieces recently and would appreciate any help finding out which LEGO sets they are from.

[image: curved slope with sticker with fine lines]

[image: over the wheel piece]

Answer (score 11):

These are:

- [Wedge 6 x 4 Triple Curved with Scales Pattern Model Right (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43712pb009R&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

from set [8075: Neptune Carrier](https://brickset.com/sets/8075-1/Neptune-Carrier)

and

- [Wedge 8 x 3 x 2 Open Left with Long Orange Claw Pattern (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41750pb009&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

from set [8076: Deep Sea Striker](https://brickset.com/sets/8076-1/Deep-Sea-Striker)

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Coincidentally both nautical-themed, though you wouldn't guess that at first glance...